# Login Authentication with Email using UserDetailService in SpringSecurity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to login with Email instead of UserName using Spring Security UserDetailService authentication but I can't able to login and get

> org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException.

When I debug codes, debugger does not go after

> Users user = userDao.findByUserName(useremail); from UserServiceImpl.java and occurred error.

May be there is one step require more in somewhere.
Configuration and Java codes and Error Logs are as below:-

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/customer/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/product/productList/all" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userServiceImpl">
                <security:password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="userServiceImpl" class="com.emusicstore.service.impl.UserServiceImpl" />

    <bean id="bcryptEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" >
    <constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </bean>
```

**Login.jsp**

```
<form name="loginForm" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />" method="post">

                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                    <div class="error" style="color: #ff0000;">${error}</div>
                </c:if>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Email : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Passwrod:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
            </form>
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.jaas.AuthorityGranter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.emusicstore.dao.UserDao;
import com.emusicstore.model.Users;
import com.emusicstore.service.UserService;
@Service
@Transactional
@Qualifier("userServiceImpl")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String useremail)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = userDao.findByUserEmail(useremail);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserName or Password Invalid.");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getEnabled(), true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(userDao.getUserRole(user.getUsersId())));
    }

    private final List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(final List<String> roleList) {
        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (final String role : roleList) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
}
}
```

**Console Error as below:**

> ERROR:
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
>   - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user. org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.emusicstore.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserServiceImpl.java:33)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:102)
>     ... 35 more

Kindly help me overcome through above errors.

Thank You Very Much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Users user = userDao.findByUserEmail(useremail);
```

Above `userDao.findByUserEmail(useremail);` returns null value.

Comment: I was mistakenly put this code <bean id="userServiceImpl" class="com.emusicstore.service.impl.UserServiceImpl" /> in ApplicationContext.xml which on runtime spring can't find the service to autowired, but actually it should be under my dispatcher-servlet.xml. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its a simple **NullPointerException** in your custom code. Put breakpoint in in UserServiceImpl.java at 33 and check.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.emusicstore.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserServiceImpl.java:33)

Answer (score 0):

In my case [this link](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-service-delays-startup-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-4-15-0-24/6205/16) helped. It was snapd issue.